# A bit confused about generics and types

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like this (greatly simplified code):

```
public class MyClass 
{

   private Type _listingType = typeof(AntiqueSellerListing);

   public DeleteEntity(int id) 
   {
       // This is what I would like to do, but it does not compile
       SystemLogic.DeleteItem<this._listingType>(id);

       // But this does
       SystemLogic.DeleteItem<AntiqueSellerListing>(id);
   }    
}
```

The DeleteItem method is defined as follows:

```
public void DeleteItem<T>(int primaryKeyValue) where T : class
```

I'm probably missing something simple here, but I'm not sure how to do what I want to do.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need the runtime type (as opposed to the compile-time type obtained through `typeof`)? If that's really the case, you should probably be using polymorphism rather than generics.

Comment: Why do you want to do the former rather than the latter? It looks like you just want to make DeleteEntity generic as well to me but in the given example you're hardcoding things so its hard to see how the type is going to vary (assuming it will).

Comment: Maybe do some research about generics versus reflection? They are two entirely separate things. I see why there might be confusion, but when you understand both you'll see why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type has to be a compile time expression so that the runtime can generate the code for the method. This is because the runtime can not guarantee that a variable will be defined prior to the code being generated. For example the Ngen tool allows the code to be precompiled without running any code.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your going to want to add an interface which describes your 'generic' methods. As long as the type satisfies the contract of the interface, you'll be fine.

```
public interface IListing
{
    void DeleteItem(int id);
}

public AntiqueSellerListing : IListing
{
    public void DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        ... delete logic
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void DeleteEntity<T>(T listing, int id)
        where T : IListing
    {
        SystemLogic.DeleteItem<T>(listing, id);
    }    
}

public static class SystemLogic
{
    public void DeleteItem<T>(T listing, int id)
        where T : IListing
    {
        listing.DeleteItem(id);
    }  
}
```

I've written this off the bat but the general idea is there.